# open custom app from google assistant on smartPhone

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai

Here's the problem,
i'm developing an google assistant app where i should show a list to the user and when he press on item from the list i should open another app.
i was able to create list using the following :-

```
app.askWithList(app.buildRichResponse()
      .addSimpleResponse('Alright')
      .addSuggestions(
        ['Basic Card', 'List', 'Carousel', 'Suggestions']),
      app.buildList('Things to learn about')
      .addItems(app.buildOptionItem('MATH_AND_PRIME', ['math', 'math and prime', 'prime numbers', 'prime'])
        .setTitle('Math & prime numbers')
        .setDescription('42 is an abundant number because the sum of its ' +
          'proper divisors 54 is greater…')
        .setImage('http://example.com/math_and_prime.jpg', 'Math & prime numbers'))
      .addItems(app.buildOptionItem('EGYPT', ['religion', 'egpyt', 'ancient egyptian'])
        .setTitle('Ancient Egyptian religion')
        .setDescription('42 gods who ruled on the fate of the dead in the ' +
          'afterworld. Throughout the under…')
        .setImage('http://example.com/egypt', 'Egypt')
      )
      .addItems(app.buildOptionItem('RECIPES', ['recipes', 'recipe', '42 recipes'])
        .setTitle('42 recipes with 42 ingredients')
        .setDescription('Here\'s a beautifully simple recipe that\'s full ' +
          'of flavor! All you need is some ginger and…')
        .setImage('http://example.com/recipe', 'Recipe')
      )
    );
```

do any one have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Assistant doesn't support push messages, so you need to send a push message using Fcm/Gcm from your fulfillment when the user select something. It means you need to implement push messages in your app, you need account linking and an oauth2 server. A lot of work at least at the moment.

Comment: so , as a work around can i even open an url when i select item in the list ?

Comment: Yes, you send an url and when user selects the item, the browser will be opened

Comment: sorry but how to do it ?

Comment: Asking how to send a URL is a slightly different problem, and best done by asking another question on StackOverflow

Comment: @MohamedMitwaly Stackoverflow is not a forum, upvote (if you want) and accept the answer if it replies to your question. Another question? Then ask a new question.